# Wordpress custom css classes not being applied to menu items

Tags: css, wordpress, class, menu

I'm trying to add a custom class to a menu item from the admin appearance->Menus page. It's not working with the theme I'm using (yootheme). I also tried the next code block but no success...the classes are not showing up in the source on the website...It's a yootheme issue, they have their own classes system.

I am creating a responsive layout with css breakpoints and I want to hide some menu item for specific breakpoints, this is why the menu items must have an ID or a class.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if($item->title == 'login'){
         $classes[] = 'sample';
      }
 return $classes;
}
```

thank you

Comment: When you say "not working", do you mean that the classes are not showing up in the source on the website at all, or do you mean that the classes DO show up but their styles aren't working.

Comment: the classes are not showing up in the source on the website. It's a yootheme issue, they have their own classes system. I need to bypass that but I dont know how

Comment: Your code is ok to me, are you sure the title of your item is "login"?

Comment: yes it's the menu item title/text...